# Will an Android WebView render HTML scraped from the body of a forum thread?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm attempting to make an app for a forum(just for fun and experience) and I got a lot of it planned out and some of it implemented but I'm not sure how I should go about displaying the body of the forum post. This is where I'm a little stumped.

Right now I have it so it scrapes the html from the body of the post in the thread that is currently being viewed. I'm not sure about the best/quickest way to display this text to the user. A lot of it is html. I pretty much grabbed everything inside a blockquote. Like I said, a lot of it is raw html. I'm wondering if I could use a webview to render and display this html to a user. I've never used a webview before and want to plan this out so I don't get too far into this and find out it doesn't work.

The other choice of what I can do is a little tedious. I would have to look through all the html and create an algorithm to check for tags(img, a, b, ect.) At least that's the only other way I can think of, with my limited experience, that would accomplish my task.

This is the first time I've tried making an app like this. It's all in good fun and experience. What are your thoughts? I'm wondering if this is how a webview works. I've never used a webview like this myself.

EDIT:Alright guys... I found a better and simple answer to my problem. It pains me that I was doing the more complicated solution but at least I understand a little about the WebView now. xD Apparently you can parse html using the Html class's fromHtml(String) method and even put this in your TextView. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is the WebView method loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding). If you have the html in a String, you can open it in the WebView with

```
 myWebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

However things like links will not work if you load the html this way. If you want those to work you can use the method loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl) and provide the base Url of the forum. (historyUrl can be null.) Check out the [WebView doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for more information.

Comment: Alright... I implemented the webview to display the post's body. It works! :) only there is a problem... The posts are displayed in a listview. The webview within the listview takes a long time to load. I'm using an old Samsung Galaxy S2 so this probably wouldn't be a problem with a newer phone. Is there any way to speed up the performance?

Comment: are WebViews normally this slow?